# Implement jQuery addClass to a modal dialog button

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#addLocation" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 820,
        width: 550,
        buttons: {
            "Add Location": function() {
                document.forms['mapform'].submitted.value='1';
                document.forms["mapform"].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
});
});
```

How can I implement the `addClass` function to the 'Add Location' button on the modal dialog?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make buttons an array and set the button as an object

```
    buttons: [{
        text: "Add Location",
        click: function() {
            document.forms['mapform'].submitted.value='1';
            document.forms["mapform"].submit();
        },
        class: "myCssClass"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

does `$(this).addClass("myCssClass")`

not work?

And if not, let the browser rendering the button and add aftwardes the the css class.

Comment: try the option dialogClass (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass) and bind the css class to the html tag button. I think this is the only one option do you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#addLocation").dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset button:eq(0)").addClass("");
```

You just need to set the correct index for :eq()